# trying to retrieve data from one datatable and i am trying to populate another datatable based on certain conditions using C# i am unable to do so

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using the code below.

I get data table data fine in dta.

Now in GCSdt1, I want to populate the data such that for each employee I want to show the user shift in columns for that month. I mean to say the table should look like

`Name | 6-1-2015|6-2-2015|.........|6-30-2015` and next row should be under name it should show name, under 6-1-2015 it should show the shift he is on for 6-1-2015

Below is my code. I am able to get till populating first data table and creating the columns for the grid. Now i am stuck.

```
    SqlDataReader GCSrdr;
    SqlCommand GCScmd;
    DataRow GCSdrow;
    DataView GTView;
    DataTable GCSdt = new DataTable();
    DataTable GCSdt1 = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection GCScon = new SqlConnection("MYCOnnection");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Date;
    static DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

    DataColumn[] day1;



    static int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month);

    DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
    DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, daysInMonth);

    public DataTable MonthView()
    {

        string gcsCmdSelect = "Select S.Emp_Name,S.User_Shift,S.Shift_Emp_Status,S.Shift_Date from Shift_Details S INNER JOIN Emp_Details E ON S.EMP_Name=E.Employee_Name where (S.Shift_Date >='" + startOfMonth + "') and (S.Shift_Date <='" + endOfMonth + "')  ORDER BY S.Emp_Name";

        if (GCScon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            GCScon.Open();
        }
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(gcsCmdSelect, GCScon);
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dta);
       /////// Results fine


        DataView ndtv = new DataView(dta);
        GCSdt = ndtv.ToTable(true,dta.Columns[0].ToString());


        GCSdt1.Columns.Add("Name");
        for (int i = 1; i <=daysInMonth; i++)
        {

            GCSdt1.Columns.Add(startOfMonth.ToShortDateString());
            startOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddDays(1);
        }

          GCSdt1.Rows.Add();
```

/////////////////////Stuck Here//////////////////////

```
        return GCSdt1;


    }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT concatenate query strings. Use parameterized queries http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: I am able to retrieve the data fine from database to data table my problem is different

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question. I was trying to say that your query is open to injections.

Comment: Sorry Nath, i am very new to C#, if you can help me it would be great help, I  am stuck at a point on pop luting the second GCSdt1. Really need some help with urgency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dta = new DataTable();
            dta.Columns.Add("Emp_Name", typeof(string));

            dta.Columns.Add("User_Shift", typeof(string));
            dta.Columns.Add("Shift_Emp_Status", typeof(string));
            dta.Columns.Add("Shift_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dta.Columns["Shift_Date"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/1/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/2/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Afternoon", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/3/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/14/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/15/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", "Afternoon", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/26/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/15/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Morning", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/22/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Evening", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/23/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Afternoon", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/24/15") });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Morning", "abc", null });
            dta.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", "Evening", "abc", DateTime.Parse("1/26/15") });

            DataTable displayTable = new DataTable();
            DateTime firstDayOfMonth = DateTime.Parse("1/1/15");
            int numberOfDaysInMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;
            DateTime dayCounter = firstDayOfMonth;

            displayTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDaysInMonth; i++)
            {
                displayTable.Columns.Add(dayCounter.ToShortDateString(), typeof(string));
                dayCounter = dayCounter.AddDays(1);
            }


            var results = dta.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Emp_Name"))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    name = x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("Emp_Name")).FirstOrDefault(),
                    shifts = x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("User_Shift")).ToList(),
                    days = x.Select(y => y.Field<object>("Shift_Date")).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var row in results)
            {
                string[] shifts = new string[numberOfDaysInMonth + 1];
                shifts[0] = row.name;
                for (int i = 0; i < row.days.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (row.days[i] != null)
                    {
                        int dayOfMonth = ((DateTime)(row.days[i])).Day;
                        string shift = row.shifts[i];
                        shifts[dayOfMonth] = shift;
                    }

                }

                DataRow shiftRow = displayTable.Rows.Add(shifts);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = displayTable;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Trying it now.. will let you know

Comment: Add one to array for employee name :   string[] shifts = new string[numberOfDaysInMonth + 1];

Comment: I am getting System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at line
days = x.Select(y => y.Field<DateTime>("Shift_Date")).ToList()

Comment: Are any of your shift dates null?  Made changes to allow for null

Comment: No. But i created the dta in a different way

Comment: How do i send it to u?

Comment: The DGV rows and the DataTable rows are the same.  So the best method is to select the row of DGV to edit but make the actual changes to DataTable.  After select the DataGidView row press a button to open a form to make edits.  One the form have one box (either text or combo) for each column of DGV.  Make changes to in boxes and then save.

Comment: sorry Sir, but  i tried and was stuck with "the gridview 'gridview1' fired event rowediting which wasn't handled."